# NDEigensystem does not work when using nonlinear operator

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, nonlinear, eigenvalues

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of the stationary Gross Pitaevskii equation using the `NDEigensystem` command via

```
{vals, funcs}=NDEigensystem[{ -(1/2)*D[y[x], x, x] + V[x]*y[x] + g*Abs[y[x]]^2*y[x], y[L] == y[-L] == 0}, y, {x, -L, L}, 2];
```

Here `g` is the mean-field interaction parameter and `V[x]` a simple external potential, a square well plus a Gaussian at the center given by

```
V[x_] := (Abs[x/L])^p + (γ/(√π ξ))*Exp[-x^2/ξ^2]
```

where `p` is an exponent taken very large of order 1000, `γ` the height of the Gaussian and `ξ` a parameter determining the height and width of the Gaussian. I use `p = 1000`, `L = 0.0495`, `γ = 10`, and `ξ = 0.05` to generate a box-delta potential.

However, when I run the code, I get an error message saying

> {vals,funcs} and NDEigensystem[{(112.838 e^Times[<<2>>]+2.482*10^305 Abs[<<1>>]^1000) y[x]-0.2 Abs[y[x]]^2 y[x]-y''[x]/2,y[0.495]==y[-0.495]==0},y,{x,-0.495,0.495},2] are not the same shape.

What is the meaning of `are not the same shape`? I suspect that `NDEigensystem` cannot find the eigenvalues for a nonlinear operator? Can anyone please advise?

Comment: The help for NDEigensystem clearly states "linear differential operator".

Comment: The error means that since NDEigensystem did not work, your result is not a 2 component list and does not match the 2 component list you specified on the left side of your equation.  Even if your operator were linear, you would need to specify numerical values for everything in your equation to get a numerical result.

Comment: Although, as others already have stated, `NDEigensystem` cannot solve your problem.  However, with some work, `NDSolve` should be able to.

Comment: @user3623974 This paper could be useful  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0417.pdf

Comment: @bbgodfrey probably there is an answer somewhere here that shows the idea you have in mind. I tried to search for it, but could not find anything. Do you perhaps have a link you could share?

Comment: @user21 Your comment prompted me to answer the question.  However, there are other approaches, such as expanding the `y` in finite elements, wavelets, etc.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks for that. Much appreciated. I am starting to think if I should look for ways to extend NDEigensystem to be able to deal with nonlinear eigenvalue problems, I think there could be some merit to that. This probably should be done by implementing several methods. Your answer could be the basis for one of them.

Comment: %user21  That improvement would be very useful.  In addition to finite element expansions, there is also a method referred to as `Evans` or `CompoundMatrix` that I have seen on this site.  I have not used it and am uncertain of it limitations, but it has been used serveral times here.  There is also the documented `NDSolve` method using the eigenvalue `a` as a dependent variable with ODE a['[x]  ==  0`, but it requires an additional boundary condition.

Comment: @User21 By the way, a Holomorphic method for `NDSolve` boundary value problems also would be very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constant not defined in the question is `g`.  However, it can be identified from the error message as `g = -0.2`.  The error message also indicates that `L` should be `0.495` rather than `0.0495`.  With these values `V` is given by

```
p = 1000; L = 495 10^-3; γ = 10; ξ = 1/20; g = -1/5;
V[x_] := (Abs[x/L])^p + (γ/(Sqrt[γ] ξ))*Exp[-x^2/ξ^2]
Plot[V[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Next construct a function that, given the eigenvalue `a` and `b = y'[-L]`, returns `y[L]`, which we wish to be zero.

```
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/2)*D[y[x], x, x] + V[x]*y[x] + 
  g*Abs[y[x]]^2*y[x] == a y[x], y[-L] == 0, y'[-L] == b}, y[L], 
 {x, -L, L}, {a, b}];
```

Then, determine pairs `{a, b}` for which `f == 0`.

```
ContourPlot[f[a0, b0] == 0, {a0, -100, 100}, {b0, -100, 100}, 
  FrameLabel -> {a, b}, PlotPoints -> {100, 100}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

So, the eigenvalues appear not to be discrete.  To plot some of the corresponding eigenfunctions, arbitrarily choose `b = 1`.

```
Plot[f[a0, 1], {a0, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, "y[L]"}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

for which the zeros are

```
eigen1 = Join @@ Table[Values@FindRoot[f[a0, 1] == 0, {a0, a00}], 
  {a00, {-52, -20, 13, 20, 62, 82}}]
(* {-52.3624, -21.7713, 16.0197, 20.9797, 63.5687, 83.5629} *)
```

Now, plot the eigenfunctions.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[fs[a00, 1], {a00, eigen1[[3 ;;]]}], {x, -L, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {a, "y[L]"}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eigen1[[3 ;;]], {.1, .2}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[fs[a00, 1], {a00, eigen1[[;; 2]]}], {x, -L, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {a, "y[L]"}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eigen1[[;; 2]], {.1, .2}]]
```

[image]

At first, I was surprised by this last plot, because I had expected solutions to be either symmetric or antisymmetric.  However, asymmetric solutions should be possible, if solutions that are mirror images of the solutions shown also exist, and they do.  For instance, the mirror image of the solution for `a = -21.7713` can be obtained by

```
D[fs[eigen1[[2]], 1], x] /. x -> L
(* -69.7483 *)
fs[eigen1[[2]], 1];
fs[eigen1[[2]], -%%];
Plot[{%%, %}, {x, -L, L}]
```

[image]

Comment: To the Managers of StackExchange: I do NOT think at all that my question was just due to a simple mistake. I was asking a question that needed an expert to answer. The answers provided by the person helped us quite a lot and solved a computational problem in a research we are undertaking with collaborators in the USA. Where is the "simple mistake" you are talking about? Could you please clarify? And do you know what physics I am addressing here?

Comment: @user3623974 Probably, those who closed your question agreed with Bill Watts that the documentation explained why `NDEigensystem` failed to return an answer.  If you wish to try to have your question reopened, try editing it to state that you are seeking a work-around.  By the way, it is probable that I am the only person to see your comment here.